# Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 Get listItem(10.000.000 List Item from a SharePoint list)

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks, sharepoint-list

I am using Microsoft solution(Ref. Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for our enterprise software(CSOM+C#). We have more than 10.000.000 item in our SharePoint List and we would like to retrieve all of them to do specific transactions(ex: compare items from SharePoint List with items from a CSV-File(File Server)). How we can do it?

I am asking for your valuable solutions/suggestions.

Best,
Sezgin

Comment: First you can use Microsoft Graph API's pagination to get the good number of items in it. Then get the data, compare the SharePoint list with items from a csv file] with your business logic.

Comment: @Dev thank you very much for both your time and your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that the above helped, @Sezgin!!

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it and accepting it as answer. So it can be useful to others as well :)

Answer (score 0):

First you can use Microsoft Graph API's pagination to get the good number of items in it. Then get the data, compare the SharePoint list with items from a csv file based on your business logic.